# Data Scrape Output into Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

Hello Everyone I have Scraped this Information from a JobListing site so far. Everything seems to work well however I am struggling to get this information into a data frame with headers and everything. Any Help is appreciated.
My Full code is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd 

URL = 'https://www.monster.com/jobs/search/?q=Software-Developer&where=Australia'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find(id='ResultsContainer')

python_jobs = results.find_all('h2',string=lambda text: 'test' in text.lower())
for p_job in python_jobs:
    link = p_job.find('a')['href']
    print(p_job.text.strip())
    print(f"Apply Here: {link}")

job_elems = results.find_all('section', class_= 'card-content')

for job_elem in job_elems:
    title_elem = job_elem.find('h2', class_='title')
    company_elem = job_elem.find('div', class_='company')
    location_elem = job_elem.find('div', class_='location')
    if None in (title_elem, company_elem, location_elem):
        continue
    print(title_elem.text.strip())
    print(company_elem.text.strip())
    print(location_elem.text.strip())
    print()
```

Not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `concat()` for all columns and then `append()` to one dataframe in loop

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

URL = 'https://www.monster.com/jobs/search/?q=Software-Developer&where=Australia'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find(id='ResultsContainer')

python_jobs = results.find_all('h2',string=lambda text: 'test' in text.lower())
for p_job in python_jobs:
    link = p_job.find('a')['href']
    print(p_job.text.strip())
    print(f"Apply Here: {link}")

job_elems = results.find_all('section', class_= 'card-content')

df= pd.DataFrame()

for job_elem in job_elems:
    title_elem = job_elem.find('h2', class_='title')
    company_elem = job_elem.find('div', class_='company')
    location_elem = job_elem.find('div', class_='location')
    if None in (title_elem, company_elem, location_elem):
        continue
    df1=pd.concat([pd.Series(title_elem.text.strip()),
                  pd.Series(company_elem.text.strip()),
                  pd.Series(location_elem.text.strip())],axis=1)
    df=df.append(df1)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the job details (i.e, title, company, and location) in a dictionary, then dataframe the dictionary.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd 

URL = 'https://www.monster.com/jobs/search/?q=Software-Developer&where=Australia'
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find(id='ResultsContainer')

python_jobs = results.find_all('h2',string=lambda text: 'test' in text.lower())
for p_job in python_jobs:
    link = p_job.find('a')['href']
    print(p_job.text.strip())
    print(f"Apply Here: {link}")

job_elems = results.find_all('section', class_= 'card-content')
i = 1
my_job_list = {}
for job_elem in job_elems:
    title_elem = job_elem.find('h2', class_='title')
    company_elem = job_elem.find('div', class_='company')
    location_elem = job_elem.find('div', class_='location')
    if None in (title_elem, company_elem, location_elem):
        continue
    op = f'opening {i}'
    my_job_list[op] = {'position':title_elem.text.strip(), 'company': 
company_elem.text.strip(), 'location': location_elem.text.strip()}
    i= i+1
    print(title_elem.text.strip())
    print(company_elem.text.strip())
    print(location_elem.text.strip())

df = pd.DataFrame(my_job_list)

print(df)
```